# Have any method make HP-UX 11.31(IA64) support 64-bit time_t

Tags: c, long-integer, hp-ux, time-t, itanium

I'm be surprised to learn type long and time_t are 4-byte sized in this HP-UX 11.31(IA64). May I ask why?

My environment:

```
$ uname -a
HP-UX bdev1 B.11.31 U ia64 0999202893 unlimited-user license

$ cat /usr/include/sys/_time_t.h
......
#  ifndef _TIME_T
#    define _TIME_T
#    ifdef _KERNEL
typedef int32_t time_t;
#    else /* !_KERNEL */
_NAMESPACE_STD_START
typedef long time_t;
_NAMESPACE_STD_END
#    endif /* !_KERNEL */
#  endif /* _TIME_T */
```

My code:

```
$ cat sizeof.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

#define PRINT_SIZE(a) \
        std::cout << #a << ": " << sizeof(a) << std::endl

int main(void)
{
        PRINT_SIZE(long);
        PRINT_SIZE(time_t);
        return 0;
}

$ aCC sizeof.cpp

$ ./a.out
long: 4
time_t: 4
```

Anybody could help me to find a way making time_t to 64-bit by aCC?

Answer (score 3):

I have a hunch that for whatever reason g++ has decided to output 32-bit code on your HP-UX system. You can change the build environment with the [`-mlp64` flag](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.6/gcc/IA_002d64-Options.html), like so:

```
$ g++ -Wall -mlp64 sizeof.cpp
```

If you're using [aCC, you use `+DD64`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.udb.apdv.embed.doc%2Fdoc%2Fr0007659.htm):

```
$ aCC +DD64 sizeof.cpp
```

> The object format for HP-UX 11i v2 is ELF, so you can use the +DD64 option to generate LP64 code. *([source](http://h21007.www2.hp.com/portal/download/files/unprot/stk/solaris_stk/portguides/TITLE.HTM#d0e3842))*

Comment: I sorry to forget to point out I use aCC at work. So the problem is how to use aCC to solve it. I reedit my question.

Comment: Yes, I found this arg too. But why do the program down while year of time up 2040. I suggest it was time_t limit, but now be proved not.